# using Tcl with tdbc over MS SQL on Win x64

Tags: sql-server, odbc, tcl, tdbc

We've been using tclodbc package for running queries against MS SQL Server for a few years. Now we have to switch to x64 process and tclodbc doesn't load because there is no x64 version.

We started looking at alternatives and tried tdbc but we are having problems with character fields passed as parameters. I created a test table with 2 integer columns and 2 varchar columns (50 and 100 long).

I am trying to insert records and the following happens:
1. If I insert records providing only 2 integer parameters everything works fine - 5 records get inserted (see code below).
2. If I insert records providing only 1 character parameter 1 record gets inserted and then the script fails with the following error: "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]String data, right truncation"
3. If I pass two character parameters or an integer parameter and a character parameter then nothing gets inserted - I get the same error as above.

I didn't test any other data types but it looks like something is wrong with character parameters (I also tried nvarchar and char type columns).

Here is my code:

```
package require tdbc::odbc
set con "Driver=\{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server\};server=server;database=database;Intergrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
tdbc::odbc::connection create db $con

set insert_cmd [db prepare {INSERT INTO dbo.testing_tdbc (f50,f100) VALUES(:f50,:f100) } ]
$insert_cmd paramtype f50 char 50
$insert_cmd paramtype f100 char 100

foreach fint [list 1 2 3 4 5] {
    set fi1 $fint
    set fi2 [expr {$fi1*2}]
    set f50 "${fi2}_${fi1}"
    set f100 $f50

    $insert_cmd execute
}

$insert_cmd close
db close
```

I tried the same with ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server - all with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]String data, right
>   truncation

As you probably know, this error is caused by inserting a string longer than declared column precision.

According to *tdbc::statement* manual the syntax for `$stmt paramtype` is:

```
$stmt paramtype ?direction? type ?precision? ?scale?
```

So I am not really sure what you mean by passing `f50` as `direction` here (which should be one of: `in, inout, out`.
I think you can just omit the `$stmt paramtype` call and proceed directly to executing `$insert_cmd` using for example `$stmt execute ?dict?`:

```
set insert_cmd [db prepare {INSERT INTO dbo.testing_tdbc (f50,f100) VALUES(:f50,:f100) } ]

foreach fint {1 2 3 4 5} {
   set value [expr {$fint*2}]_$fint
   set bindings [dict create f50 $value f100 $value]
   $insert_cmd execute $bindings
}

$insert_cmd close
db close
```

Comment: I tried the code suggested by Jakub but it didn't work:<br/>
    [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]String data, right truncation
(executing the statement)
     while executing
    "::oo::Obj22::Stmt::1 resultSetCreate ::oo::Obj23::ResultSet::1 ::oo::Obj22::Stm
t::1 {f50 2_1 f100 2_1}"
    ("uplevel" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"uplevel 1  [list  [self] resultSetCreate  [namespace current]::ResultSet::[incr
 resultSetSeq]  [self] {*}$args]"
    (class "::tdbc::statement" method "execute" line 2)
    invoked from within
"$insert_cmd execute $bindings"...